# "take an umbrella" or "get an umbrella".What's the difference?

Tags: verbs

If I am going to away from my home.
I want to put an umbrella in my bag. Which sentence is correct?

Should I take an umbrella?

Should I get an umbrella?

If I am shopping.
I want to buy an umbrella.  Which sentence is correct?

What's the difference between these two verbs.

Answer (score 1):

"Take an umbrella" means to carry it with you when you go from here to somewhere else.

"Get an umbrella" means you don't have an umbrella here, and you go somewhere to pick it up.

Of course, we often use these words more metaphorically so that "here" and "somewhere else" might be very close to each other.